# onChange event issue with class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I just want to get value from Radio component (checked or unchecked) in ui-semantic having following code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      startDate: moment()
        .subtract(30, 'days')
        .startOf('day'),
      endDate: moment().endOf('day'),
      isChecked: false,
    });
  }
```

Radio component:

```
<Radio toggle className="ongoing-checkbox"
  label="Show ongoing alerts"
  value={ !this.state.isChecked }
  onChange={e => this.selectOngoingAlerts(e)}></Radio>
```

and handler function:

```
selectOngoingAlerts = (e) => {
  this.setState(this.state.isChecked = true);
  const { householdAlerts } = this.props;
  console.log('checked', this.state.isChecked);
}
```

How to have a state of Radio component in `selectOngoingAlerts` function? I want to make different actions with respect whether radio is checked or unchecked.

Comment: shouldn't this `this.setState(this.state.isChecked = true);` be `this.setState({isChecked : true});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accept the data / checked value from the second argument of the onChange callback. You were trying to assign the value in `setState` as well which is wrong. do it like you do in your `componentDidMount`

```
selectOngoingAlerts = (e, data) => {
  this.setState({isChecked: data});
}
```

Also update the radio component to just pass the callback to your handler, you dont need or want a lambda here..

```
<Radio toggle className="ongoing-checkbox"
  label="Show ongoing alerts"
  value={ !this.state.isChecked }
  onChange={this.selectOngoingAlerts} />
```

From the docs, [the second argument is where the value is passed](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/)

You should be referencing the `Checkbox` docs like I linked because the `Radio` is syntactic sugar for `<Checkbox radio />`

**Remember:** `setState` is async, so you cannot `console.log` the value like you are trying to. Instead use a callback on setState if you really want to see its updated value, or just move your `console.log` to the render so you can see the value change on render cycles.

Comment: So from componentDidMount should I delete "isChecked: false," completely?

Comment: how do you define  state on the component? meaning, if you already assign false to it, then its not needed in did mount.

Comment: In "componentDidMount" I assigned initially "true" value and works as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
selectOngoingAlerts = (e) => {
  const {isChecked} = this.state;
  this.setState({ isChecked : !isChecked });
  isChecked ? console.log('on') : console.log('off');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.